# JavaScript function which accesses Object field

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a JavaScript function which receives in parameter the field of the object we'd like to have and returns its value :

```
var object = {
    field1 : "test1",
    field2 : [
        "test2", "test3"
    ]
};
var getField = function (field){
     return object[field]; 
}
getField("field1"); // working
getField("field2[0]"); // not working due to the array
```

Am I obliged to split the parameter by "[" to get the correct field ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the correct array item you need to use:

```
getField("field2")[0] // prints "test2"
```

When using `getField("field2[0]")`, you're accessing from `object` a property with the name `"field2[0]"`, which doesn't exist and will return `undefined`.

Check more details about the [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors).